# How to conduct joint significance test in seemingly unrelated regression

Tags: r, r-car, systemfit, linearhypothesis, seemingly-unrelated-regression

I'm trying to conduct a joint test of significance in a seemingly unrelated regression setup with robust standard errors. I have three outcomes `Y1`, `Y2`, and `Y3` and I want to conduct a joint hypothesis test against the null that the average effect of the treatment `Z` is zero on all three outcomes.

I think that I have the model set up correctly, but I don't think that I have the `hypothesis.matrix` set correctly in `car::linearHypothesis`.

Here's some data:

```
library(tibble)
library(car)
library(systemfit)

set.seed(343)
N = 800
dat <-
  tibble(
    U = rnorm(N),
    Z = rbinom(N, 1, 0.5),
    Y = 0.2 * Z + U,
    Y1 = Y + rnorm(N, sd = 0.3),
    Y2 = Y + rnorm(N, sd = 0.5),
    Y3 = Y + rnorm(N, sd = 0.5)
  )
```

Here's the seemingly unrelated regression fit:

```
sur <- systemfit(list(Y1 ~ Z, Y2 ~ Z, Y3 ~ Z), method = "SUR", data = dat)
summary(sur)
```

Which is identical to the ols fit in this case:

```
ols <- lm(cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) ~ Z, data = dat)
summary(ols)
```

Which is useful, because I need to estimate robust standard errors for this test:

```
linearHypothesis(ols, hypothesis.matrix = "Z = 0", white.adjust = "hc2")
```

This last line is the one that I think is incorrect. I think it's incorrect because the individual coefficients all have lower p-values than the joint test, but I could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks right to me.  You'd get the same result by estimating the null model (`ols0` below) and using `anova()` to test the difference between the estimated and null models.

```r
library(tibble)
library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData

set.seed(343)
N = 800
dat <-
  tibble(
    U = rnorm(N),
    Z = rbinom(N, 1, 0.5),
    Y = 0.2 * Z + U,
    Y1 = Y + rnorm(N, sd = 0.3),
    Y2 = Y + rnorm(N, sd = 0.5),
    Y3 = Y + rnorm(N, sd = 0.5)
  )


ols <- lm(cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) ~ Z, data = dat)

linearHypothesis(ols, hypothesis.matrix = "Z = 0")
#> 
#> Sum of squares and products for the hypothesis:
#>          Y1       Y2       Y3
#> Y1 3.201796 4.693391 3.359617
#> Y2 4.693391 6.879863 4.924734
#> Y3 3.359617 4.924734 3.525216
#> 
#> Sum of squares and products for error:
#>          Y1       Y2       Y3
#> Y1 829.5535 756.1586 770.0808
#> Y2 756.1586 965.5959 770.4636
#> Y3 770.0808 770.4636 980.0664
#> 
#> Multivariate Tests: 
#>                  Df test stat approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)
#> Pillai            1 0.0073689  1.96972      3    796 0.11703
#> Wilks             1 0.9926311  1.96972      3    796 0.11703
#> Hotelling-Lawley  1 0.0074236  1.96972      3    796 0.11703
#> Roy               1 0.0074236  1.96972      3    796 0.11703

ols0 <- lm(cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) ~ 1, data = dat)
anova(ols, ols0, test="Pillai")
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) ~ Z
#> Model 2: cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3) ~ 1
#>   Res.Df Df Gen.var.    Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
#> 1    798     0.48198                                        
#> 2    799  1  0.48257 0.0073689   1.9697      3    796  0.117
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>